# Unit test module that invokes private functions upon promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

I'm new to unit testing in Node and hit a road block when it comes to promises. My module performs a search through the ApiController which then returns a promise. Depending on its resolve status, it invokes one of two private functions within the module.

Module:

```
module.exports.process = function(req, res) {
  let searchTerm = req.query.searchValue;

  ApiController.fetchResults(searchTerm)
    .then((results) => onReturnedResults(results), (err) => onNoResults());

  function onReturnedResults(results) {
    req.app.set('searchResults', results);
    res.redirect('/results');
  }

  function onNoResults() {
    res.render('search/search', { noResultsFound: true });
  }
};
```

Test:

```
var res = {
  viewName: '', data : {},
  render: function(view, viewData) {
    this.view = view;
    this.viewData = viewData;
  }
};

var req = { query: { searchValue: 'doesnotexist' } }

describe('When searching for results that do not exist', function() {
  it('should display a no results found message', function(done) {
    let expectedResult = {
      noResultsFound: true;
    }

    SearchController.process(req, res);

    // Assert...  
    expect(res.viewData).to.be.equal(expectedResult);
    done();
  });
})
```

What are the best practices around this and how can I 'mock' the fetchResults returned promise so that it doesn't actually fetch results from the API (whilst still invoking the private function)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If methods are scoped as closures or are private to modules, then there is no way to access them and can only be verified indirectly.  To provide a test implementation of `fetchResults` it has to be exposed in some way.

One way is to `require` `ApiController` (this may already be happening) and then use `proxyquire` or `mockery` to override the dependency.  I've worked with many test suite, who's only way to interact and provide test dependencies are through patching `require`.  Test suites become a nightmare using this method.  Cleanup, unpatching, cascading patches, all become huge time sinks, and would recommend against it if there are any other options.

Another way is to bake in the ability to change `fetchResults` implementation into your objects.  In addition to testing, making `fetchResults` configurable will help insulate your code from future changes, by helping to minimize the impact to `process` when/if the way you need to fetch results changes:

```
var Results = (function() {
  return {
    process: function(req, res) {
      let searchTerm = req.query.searchValue;

      this.fetchResults(searchTerm)
      .then((results) => this.onReturnedResults(req, res, results), (err) =>  this.onNoResults(res)),

    fetchResults: ApiController.fetchResults,     

    onReturnedResults: function(req, res, results) {
      req.app.set('searchResults', results);
      res.redirect('/results');
    },

    onNoResults: function(res) {
      res.render('search/search', { noResultsFound: true });
    }
  };

})()
```

(i haven't used javascript in a while, so i'm not sure of the best way to model the above object, but the important part is that if your test wants to override an implementation than the implementation has to be exposed, which the above code should do)

Now there is a Results object with the `fetchResults` method exposed in a way that's easily overridable

```
var fakeFetchResults = sinon.stub();
fakeFetchResults.return(aFakePromiseWithResultsToTriggerResultsCodePath);
Results.fetchResult = fakeFetchResults;
```

The above exposes the return function and the error function, which also allow for isolated unit tests of that functionality.

Using process is done through the results object, your controller could register

`Results.process`

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful :)